# How to specify different cache.path (w/ filename) in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

In R markdown, if I want to save cahce in some other directory than the file-directory. For this, in the chuck, I will specify

`{r chunkName, cache=TRUE, cache.path=cache.path = "../cache_filename/"}`

But how to avoid typing filename? Is there a way that it can take `title` name or `filename` without .Rmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`knitr` automatically sets the `cache.path` based on the input filename.  If you want to do it differently, you could do something like this:

````
```{r}
origCache <- knitr::opts_chunk$get("cache.path")
base <- sub("_cache/.*$", "", origCache)
cat("The base of the filename is ", base)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.path = paste0(base, "_new_cache"))
```
````

Now the cache will be set to the base part of the filename followed by "_new_cache".